# Contact changes tracking problem in android

Tags: android

I am using a content observer to listen to contact changes in android 2.x (ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI). My problem is ContactObserver's onChange gets called even when I make a phone call. How can i skip these and listen only to address book changes?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Uri
to ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI
or
ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI